Instagram's "ig.me" URL is not working when visited from website
I placed the link on my website https://ig.me/m/<profile-name> with target="_blank" attribute - to open in new tab.
When I click the link, Instagram page throws 5xx server error. When I paste the same URL into address bar it navigates to expected destination. How can I get the link working on my website.

That's likely because ig.me links are not supported on Instagram Web. You have the open the link on a mobile device. Also, make sure the Instagram app is set to open supported links by default, or the mobile browser might end up opening this link instead.

Well documentation says "You can use them on your website, email newsletters and more." so ain't got a clue what they mean by "Instagram Web". As I said when I paste the link directly into address bar, it works.

As an alternative the https://instagram.com/m/<profile-name> seems to be working fine.
